# How Can I Get Radio Button Value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

How Can I Get checked Radio Button Value Only of Groups from Radio Buttons and when checked another radio it must remove old checked radio value and add new one
This is The Function

```
    const CheckRadio = (e) => {
    let values = 0;
    let RadioInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=${e.target.name}]`);
    for(let radio of RadioInputs){
        values += Number(radio.value) ;
        if(radio.checked){
            setModifiresCost(ModifiresCost + (Number(radio.value) <= values ? Number(radio.value) : 0) );
            values -= Number(radio.value);
            setSelectedModifire([...SelectedModifire , JSON.parse(radio.getAttribute('data-item'))]);
        }else{
            setModifiresCost(ModifiresCost - (Number(radio.value) - values < 0 ? 0 : Number(radio.value)) );
            let NewModifires = SelectedModifire.filter(item => item.id !== JSON.parse(radio.getAttribute('data-item')).id);
            setSelectedModifire(NewModifires);
        }
    }
}
```

and This the JSX Code

```
<div className="choices ">
                                                    {addon.addons.map(itm => (
                                                        <label key={itm.id} className="modifier custom-control custom-radio d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" onChange={CheckRadio} >
                                                            <div className='p-1'>
                                                                <input value={itm.price} data-item={JSON.stringify(itm)} className="custom-control-input OneChoice" name={`myradio${i}`} type="radio"  />
                                                                <div className="custom-control-label">{itm.name}</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            {itm.price == 0 ? (null) : (
                                                                <span>{itm.price} {Order.SpecItem.prices ? Order.SpecItem.prices.currency : null} </span>
                                                            )}
                                                        </label>
                                                    ))}
                                                </div>
```

Comment: You should use the same name property for all select inputs that belong to the same group.

Comment: yeah that's what I did, i did it dynamically, the problem is removing the old value of checked radio